# Max column value of related django model where condition is true

Tags: django, django-orm

TAssignment model has many entries related to TSlot model like for 1 pk of TSlot model there are many entries in TAssignment model.Now this queries outputs values from Tslot table and also latest related created on and updated on from Tassignment table.But what i want is latest value of
'assignment_Slot__created_on' and 'assignment_Slot__updated_on' when assignment_Slot__is_deleted=False.

QUESTION: How to add "assignment_Slot__is_deleted=False" condition along with 'assignment_Slot__created_on' and 'assignment_Slot__updated_on' inside annotate without duplicating results.

** assignment_Slot here is related name

```
TSlot.objects.filter(request__id=request_id, is_deleted=False
                ).values("slot_date", "type_of_work", "reason_for_less_assign", "request_id","slot", "remarks",
                slot_id=F("id"), request_status=F('request__request_status')).annotate(
                assigned_on=Max('assignment_Slot__created_on'), modified_on =Max('assignment_Slot__modified_on'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter-1) to your annotations, see [filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

```
from django.db.models import Max, Q, DateField

TSlot.objects.filter(...).annotate(
    assigned_on=Max('assignment_Slot__created_on', filter=Q(assignment_Slot__is_deleted=False), output_field=DateField()),
    modified_on=Max('assignment_Slot__modified_on', filter=Q(assignment_Slot__is_deleted=False), output_field=DateField())
)
```

Comment: it says "'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'" after adding filter

Comment: @PravinMishra seems like you have malformed data in your table. Can you share the models? How did you insert the data and what DB are you using?

Comment: it is like this "2022-02-25 17:36:07" for both created_on and modified on.There are only 20 entries.Query works without inside "filter=Q(assignment_Slot__is_deleted=False)"

Comment: In postman it shows this without filter:                 "assigned_on": "2022-03-04T06:02:32Z",
                "modified_on": "2022-03-04T11:32:32Z",

Comment: @ add this , filter=Q(assignment_Slot__is_deleted=False), output_field=DateField() .I will accept the answer.

Comment: @PravinMishra aha, good catch